# Bootstrap Glyphicons Rotate on Data Toggle Collapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want my glyphicons to rotate when I toggle the menu using data-toggle="collapse" using CSS only. I have got it working, but the glyphicons are facing the wrong way to start with until you open, then close and it works fine.

This is how it appears when I first load the page (should be facing to the right):
http://puu.sh/cKGnV/765032b612.png

When I open the menu they stay the same, which is the correct way as above which is correct.
Then once I close them, they face to the right which is also the correct way.

Here is an example on my website: http://ncoll-central.com/example

```css
.toggle:after {
    /* symbol for "opening" panels */
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content: "\e114";
    float: right;
    color: #999999;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.toggle.collapsed:after {
    /* symbol for "collapsed" panels */
    content: "\e080";
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar-wrapper">
  <ul class="sidebar-nav">
    <li class="sidebar-brand">
      <a href="#">Heading</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li>
      <a class="toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Menu 1</a>
      <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse sub-item">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a class="toggle" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseTwo">Menu 2</a>
      <div id="collapseTwo" class="collapse sub-item">
        <div class="list-group">
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
          <a href="#">Empty</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

From what I can tell, it's as if the code is recognising them as if they were expanded by default, when in fact they aren't.

Is there a simple solution to this, I have missed something? I would prefer to use CSS only.
Thanks!

**Solution:**

```
 <a class="toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Menu 1</a>
```

It's as simple as adding `collapsed` to the element.

Comment: Add `collapsed` class by default to the element.

Comment: @anpsmn Thanks, worked perfectly, can't believe I missed that. This little thing was bugging me for ages.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
 <a class="toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">Menu 1</a>
```

It's as simple as adding `collapsed` to the element.